# pg-promise: support polymorphic types

Tags: pg-promise

I have the following **polymorphic** function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_value_existence(
    p_value anynonarray,
    p_column_name information_schema.sql_identifier,
    p_table_name name,
    p_schema_name information_schema.sql_identifier DEFAULT 'public'::character varying)
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
...
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

and I am calling it as follows:

```
 db.func("check_value_existence", [account.username, "username", "account", "customer"])
 .then(found => { ...})
 .catch(error => {...});
```

but I get the following error:

```
could not determine polymorphic type because input has type unknown
```

When I normally call the function I always use, when required, **typecast** `::text` for the `p_value`; for example:

```
SELECT check_value_existence('username_1'::text, 'username', 'account', 'customer');
```

I suspect that pg-promise doesn't support polymorphic types, does it?

Tia

Answer (score 1):

Method [func](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#func) is there only to support the simplest scenario, which doesn't require any type casting. If you do require type casting, then do not use it, use the standard query instead, with the casting.

In case of a function that returns a single value, you can use:

```
db.one('SELECT * FROM check_value_existence($1::text, $2, $3, $4)', [account.username, 'username', 'account', 'customer'])
.then(data => {
    // data
})
.catch(error => {
    // error
})
```

> I suspect that pg-promise doesn't support polymorphic types, does it?

This is irrelevant. The library simply executes queries, with whatever types you specified in them.